# For loop returning blank output when used in conjunction with map function

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, filter

I have defined a `factorial` function which looks as below:

```
def fact(n):
    return 1 if n < 2 else n * fact(n-1)
```

Now, I am running `map` function as below:

```
results = map(fact, range(1,5))
for x in results:
    print(x)

Output:
    1
    2
    6
    24
```

I am completely understanding the above output. However, if I run the same for loop again I am getting a blank output which I am not able to understand.

```
for x in results:
    print(x)

Output:
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because in python3 map function returns a [iterator](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterators-in-python/). When you traverse generator it becomes exhausted and empty, so trying to traverse it again is like traverse empty list.

```
print(results) # <map object at 0x10a392310>
```

if you want to traverse it more than once, you can convert it to list

```
results = list(map(fact, range(1,5)))
```

Answer (score 1):

`results` is a `map` object, which is a generator.  Elements are generated as you iterate through the `map`, and it doesn't reset when you start a new iteration.

If you want it to behave like a list, you could explicitly convert the `map` to a `list` like this:

```
results = list(map(fact, range(1,5)))
```

or just use a list comprehension instead of `map`:

```
results = [fact(n) for n in range(1, 5)]
```